# Inconsistent results with random rolls and some math

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I'm working on making a program to roll 4 6 sided dice and do some simple math and logic with them.  I was running a very rough draft of the program and started to notice that the number of rolls would be inconsistent.  In particular I would sometimes wont get the smallest value or get two

If looked around for a solution online to no avail.  I even copied the code from other examples on how to find the smallest value

```
public class test {
    private static int dice(int s) {
        int num = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        num = random.nextInt(s);
        num = num + 1;
        return num;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> rolls = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i != 4; i++) {
            rolls.add(dice(6));
        }
        for (Integer roll : rolls) {
            System.out.println(roll);
        }
        int min = rolls.get(0);
        int index = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < rolls.size(); x++) {
            if (rolls.get(x) < min) {
                min = rolls.get(x);
                index = x;
                System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);
            }
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (int x : rolls) {
            sum += x;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
    }
}
```

This should generate 4 rolls of 6 sided dice.  Then it should find the smallest value print that, then calculate the sum and print it

Comment: What do you mean by _"would sometimes wont get the smallest value or get two"_? Can you show some concrete expected and unexpected outputs? First guess would be to move the `System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);` out of the loop.

Comment: Why are you re-initializing `random` with every call to `dice()`?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this bit of code:

```
int min = rolls.get(0);
int index = 0;
for(int x = 0; x<rolls.size(); x++){
    if(rolls.get(x) < min){
       min=rolls.get(x);
       index = x;
       System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);
    }
}
```

What happens if `rolls.get(0);` is your minimum roll?  In that case, `if(rolls.get(x) < min)` will always be false, and you'll never print "Smallest...".

Also note that every time you find a roll that is smaller than the last one you looked at, you print out "Smallest..." again, so if you have multiple dice in descending size, you'll print that line out multiple times.

Set your initial `min` value to 7, so you're guaranteed to have a min value that is smaller than the initial state.  And then, instead of printing inside your loop, save the min and print "Smallest..." once the loop is finished:

```
// Be aware that this code doesn't work correctly if your List is empty.
int min = 7; // You could also set this to rolls.get(0) and start your loop at 1
for (int x = 0; x < rolls.size(); x++) {
    if (rolls.get(x) < min) {
        min = rolls.get(x);
    }
}
System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);
```

(I also removed `index`, because it's not being used anywhere in your code).

---

If you wanted to be a bit more modern with this (and also more robust), you could also do:

```
rolls.stream()
     .min(Integer::compareTo)
     .ifPresent(min -> System.out.println("Smallest: " + min));
```

That will handle the case of `rolls` being empty by just not printing anything.